# Minimize redirects

Tags: wordpress, redirect, woocommerce, seo

When I check my web site with the https://gtmetrix.com, it has very low score (39), it writes that "Minimize redirects", to many redirects as below. I googled it and it says maybe bacause of a plugin named "Simple Share Buttons". But I am not using this plugin. I deactivated all plugins and tested and results is nearly same. I dont use any ads, just one trip advisor link only.

I want to ask how can I find what cause this redirects and how an I stop it?

Remove the following redirect chain if possible:

```
https://idsync.rlcdn.com/709980.gif?partner_uid=83584093-8694-4be0-b577-27ebdeae3135
https://idsync.rlcdn.com/1000.gif?memo=CNyqKxIwCiwIARDlzwkaJDgzNTg0MDkzLTg2OTQtNGJlMC1iNTc3LTI3ZWJkZWFlMzEzNRAAGg0IscKN8QUSBQjoBxAAQgBKAA
https://pippio.com/api/sync?pid=5324&it=1&iv=d6bd174b6cfff1145c4907218bf920f7a67a3c974fba91bd584676bcce283db2791426b5417dce21&_=2
https://cm.g.doubleclick.net/pixel?google_nid=pippio_dmp&google_cm&google_no_sc&m=CMwpElsKVwgBEJInGlBkNmJkMTc0YjZjZmZmMTE0NWM0OTA3MjE4YmY5MjBmN2E2N2EzYzk3NGZiYTkxYmQ1ODQ2NzZiY2NlMjgzZGIyNzkxNDI2YjU0MTdkY2UyMRAAGgwIssKN8QUSBAgCEABCAEoA
https://pippio.com/api/sync/ddp?pid=2&m=CMwpElsKVwgBEJInGlBkNmJkMTc0YjZjZmZmMTE0NWM0OTA3MjE4YmY5MjBmN2E2N2EzYzk3NGZiYTkxYmQ1ODQ2NzZiY2NlMjgzZGIyNzkxNDI2YjU0MTdkY2UyMRAAGgwIssKN8QUSBAgCEABCAEoA&google_gid=CAESEHsmYzePbc3BjUysQEIRYlE&google_cver=1
https://tags.rd.linksynergy.com/rcs?ns=lr&uid3=
https://idsync.rlcdn.com/458249.gif?partner_uid=1e184724-70da-439f-8b77-2c39e3da28c1
```

Remove the following redirect chain if possible:

```
https://pixel.sojern.com/pixel/partner/img/eh8nG4NDXWvIHGsf/hp
https://cm.g.doubleclick.net/pixel?google_cm=&google_hm=smaYOiP1RKg1HU9p0V7geQ&google_nid=sojern__adx_open_bidder_seat&sjrn_id=Q8Bu2GpA7m5gN7-XexTe_eCkWcwpLcNIUKtTBidrjiTA3riyH07nCx7WN31tM4ir
https://cm.g.doubleclick.net/pixel?google_cm=&google_hm=smaYOiP1RKg1HU9p0V7geQ&google_nid=sojern__adx_open_bidder_seat&sjrn_id=Q8Bu2GpA7m5gN7-XexTe_eCkWcwpLcNIUKtTBidrjiTA3riyH07nCx7WN31tM4ir&google_tc=
https://pixel.sojern.com/idSync/AdX?exchangeProfileId=&sjrn_id=Q8Bu2GpA7m5gN7-XexTe_eCkWcwpLcNIUKtTBidrjiTA3riyH07nCx7WN31tM4ir&google_gid=CAESELDlGqpPxgJ82kFGFR7CfBA&google_cver=1
```

Remove the following redirect chain if possible:

```
https://tag.yieldoptimizer.com/ps/ps?t=i&p=1374&pg=gsh&sync=1&si=st-profile&uex=83584093-8694-4be0-b577-27ebdeae3135
https://tag.yieldoptimizer.com/ps/ps?tc=907229868&t=i&p=1374&pg=gsh&sync=1&si=st-profile&uex=83584093-8694-4be0-b577-27ebdeae3135
https://cm.g.doubleclick.net/pixel?google_nid=yo&google_hm=NDAxMDcxOTM4NDM1Mg&google_sc&google_cm
https://tag.yieldoptimizer.com/ps/cmap?t=i&n=20&x=&google_gid=CAESEAE9JNVxkUFvE_ywsPBF3F4&google_cver=1
```

Remove the following redirect chain if possible:

```
https://match.adsrvr.org/track/cmf/generic?ttd_pid=syf1g3l&ttd_tpi=1
https://match.adsrvr.org/track/cmb/generic?ttd_pid=syf1g3l&ttd_tpi=1
https://p.travelsmarter.net/api/usersync/chain.gif?partner=ttd&partner_user=253cd788-f701-4d97-b15d-3c8625e56bdd
```

Remove the following redirect chain if possible:

```
https://sync.crwdcntrl.net/map/c=11669/tp=STRL/?https%3A%2F%2Fp.travelsmarter.net%2Fapi%2Fusersync%2Fchain.gif%3Fpartner%3Dlotame%26partner_user%3D%24%7Bprofile_id%7D
https://sync.crwdcntrl.net/map/ct=y/c=11669/tp=STRL/?https%3A%2F%2Fp.travelsmarter.net%2Fapi%2Fusersync%2Fchain.gif%3Fpartner%3Dlotame%26partner_user%3D%24%7Bprofile_id%7D
https://p.travelsmarter.net/api/usersync/chain.gif?partner=lotame&partner_user=34370169bf822ac24de780eb9f60998
```

Remove the following redirect chain if possible:

```
https://aa.agkn.com/adscores/g.pixel?sid=9212293778
https://p.travelsmarter.net/api/usersync/chain.gif?partner=neustar&partner_user=
```

Remove the following redirect chain if possible:

```
https://aa.agkn.com/adscores/rst.pixel?sid=9212297288
https://static.agkn.com/spacer.gif
```

Remove the following redirect chain if possible:

```
https://tags.bluekai.com/site/55130?limit=0&id=83584093-8694-4be0-b577-27ebdeae3135&redir=https%3A%2F%2Fp.travelsmarter.net%2Fapi%2Fusersync%2Fchain.gif%3Fpartner%3Dbluekai%26partner_user%3D%24_BK_UUID
https://p.travelsmarter.net/api/usersync/chain.gif?partner=bluekai&partner_user=Pkm%2FJx9999Og%2BiBK
```

Remove the following redirect chain if possible:

```
https://www.jscache.com/wejs?wtype=cdsratingsonlynarrow&uniq=136&locationId=19638176&lang=tr&border=true&shadow=true&backgroundColor=gray&display_version=2
https://www.tripadvisor.com/wejs?wtype=cdsratingsonlynarrow&uniq=136&locationId=19638176&lang=tr&border=true&shadow=true&backgroundColor=gray&display_version=2
```

Comment: P.s. trip advisor sets a lot of cookies and communicates with a lot of external APIs and other services. I'd do some research into that "trip advisor link" also.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **SEO** which is off-topic at Stack Overflow. Please read ["Which SEO questions should be closed as non-programming/non-admin?"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382618) to better understand when SEO questions are acceptable to ask here (most are not) and where you might be able to get assistance.

Comment: Hi, as I said I closed tripadvisor link but still problem continues. But it is not about seo actuay t is abaout web site speed because I dont know where this links come from maybe I am hacked.. Seo realy not important now, but my web site crawls..

Answer (score 0):

Majority of the results that you posted appear to be linked to trip advisor (travelsmarter, tripadvsior) as well as doubleclick and agkn which I believe is an adclick service. The others appear to be CDNs or caching, or ping services and there are also APIs in there. Disable the trip advisor plugin/services you are using and try the tests again.

Comment: Thank you for your promt reply. It is just trip advisors html code, okey removed it but nearly nothing changed. Just 2 redirecton lost and other are remaning, how can I find what causes this, I am suspicious about hacked web site?